# How do I replace an element in the DOM with one created in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a need to append data into a given  element, but not at the bottom of that element.  I have placed a placeholder, specifically a  element in the proper location, which works fine.  The following code should allow me to define and replace each of these in sequence with elements generated in javascript.  But when I try to use it, it doesn't work, throwing errors that state the node was not found.

I have tried swapping the values in replaceChild() which purportedly will do what I wish to do.  Failed.

I have tried replacing the entire command with a direct and brutal `document.getElementsByTagName("placeholder")[0] = placeholders[placeholder]` which did nothing at all.

I have tested the rest of the code, piece by piece, to eliminate any chance that there's a simple error somewhere higher up, but up to the point of the actual attempt to replaceChild everything is as it should be, at least to my eyes.

```
    var placeholders = [];
    placeholders.push(document.createElement('IMG'));
    placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].alt = 'A sample of raw magicite';
    placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].src =
      document.imagedirectory + 'magicite.png';
    placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].style.border = '3px double black';
    placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].style.height = '100px';
    placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].style.width = '100px';

    for (var placeholder = 0; placeholder < placeholders.length; placeholder++) {
      if (document.getElementsByTagName('placeholder').length > 0) {
        try {
          document
            .getElementById('pagedata')
            .replaceChild(
              document.getElementsByTagName('placeholder')[0],
              placeholders[placeholder]
            );
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(
            'Failure: Attempt to append ' +
              placeholders[0].src +
              ' into the existing content, replacing one of the placeholders.'
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

In the present state, the empty catch eats the error message.  If I remove that and run it raw, execution stops on the `document.getElementById("pagedata").replaceChild(document.getElementsByTagName("placeholder")[0], placeholders[placeholder])` line with the error of NotFoundError: Node was not found

Even though document.getElementsByTagName("placeholder")[0] is a valid element, as is placeholders[placeholder].  I'm stumped.  Any thoughts on the probably boneheaded mess I have made of this and how I can remedy it?

Edit 1: Adding at a commenter request.

```js
document.imagedirectory = "https://iolarawiki.000webhostapp.com/wiki/img/"

var placeholders = [];
placeholders.push(document.createElement("IMG"));
placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].alt = "A sample of raw magicite";
placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].src = document.imagedirectory + "magicite.png";
placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].style.border = "3px double black";
placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].style.height = "100px";
placeholders[placeholders.length - 1].style.width = "100px";

for (var placeholder = 0; placeholder < placeholders.length; placeholder++) {
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("placeholder").length > 0) {
    try {
      document.getElementById("pagedata").replaceChild(document.getElementsByTagName("placeholder")[0], placeholders[placeholder]);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Failure: Attempt to append " + placeholders[0].src + " into the existing content, replacing one of the placeholders.");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<BODY>
  <DIV ID="pagedata">
    Some content here
    <BR>
    <PLACEHOLDER>
    </PLACEHOLDER>
    Some more content here
    <BR>
  </DIV>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Does your html have `<placeholder>` elements?

Comment: @James Yes.  document.getElementsByTagName("placeholder")
HTMLCollection [ placeholder ]

Comment: Please include a sample of the HTML you are running this against. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable here, so that we can see it in action.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  A link that tries to use this code is probably easiest to see the problem in-situ.  Thank you for raising the point.  Here, take a look.  https://iolarawiki.000webhostapp.com/wiki/wiki.html?Magicite

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really work for Stack Overflow. When that URL stops working, people with the same question as you won't have any reference. Stack Overflow is meant for questions that help everyone with the same problem at any point in the future (see [ask]), and having the code, in a [mre], here on Stack Overflow, makes that possible.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Researching how to do that now.

Comment: @HereticMonkey There, that ought to do it.

Comment: Where are you coming up with a `<placeholder>` element? There is no such standard element.

Comment: The problem here is that you are using the wrong order for `replaceChild`; the first argument is the new child, the second argument is the old child.

Comment: The standard is extensible, allowing for custom tags.  I could have used a <DIV> and put a CLASS="placeholder" on it, and then added complexity to the example and my code, but why?

Comment: Custom elements, not tags, must be registered and you aren't doing that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have tried inverting the order inside replaceChild before I even posted here, as per the original post.  But that did nothing, the same error is extant.

Comment: @Rob What registration do you have in mind?  *interested look*

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html

Comment: Then there's something different in your real code. I took the snippet code, reversed the order of the arguments, and see an image, with no errors.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ok, I did preface this all with "what boneheaded thing am I doing wrong".  I -did- try inverting it before posting all this, and it didn't work.  Just did the inversion again, and now it works.  I must have typoed something when doing the first inversion attempt.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If you post that as an answer, I will flag it as the solution, if that is a thing in stackoverflow.

Comment: I'd just chalk it up to experience. We all have "brain farts" and we have a close reason just for this. Basically, this is a "typo" or "no-repro" kind of situation where the problem is not likely to help another user later. Don't sweat it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Even so, thank you for your assistance.